# How to block uploading executable files in to Alfresco Share?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, alfresco, alfresco-share

How to block uploading executable files like .exe and .msi files during the upload itself in Alfresco Share?

I don't want to allow executable files to be uploaded in to Alfresco Share. 
After googling I got one solution to create a rule which deletes executable files after upload. But that is not enough for me now. 
I need to block it at the time of upload itself.

Answer (score 3):

In the client-side upload.js like flash-upload.js there is a **setFileFilters** method, which reads from the **this.showConfig.filter** and from the object itself.

The description from the file:

```
*    filter: {array},         // limits what kind of files the user can select in the OS file selector
```

I've used this method so a client could upload another type on the action upload new version.

Add the .exe to the filter array (read it out first, don't know the exact notation anymore)

There is some more info [here](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-head/symbols/Alfresco.FileUpload.html#defaultShowConfig).

But still this doesn't fully prevent users from uploading executable files. They can still use * in their query or if they use drag-drop or webdav/cifs or another client.

If you fully want to disable it, just create a Java Behaviour which fires on onCreateNode Policy. Check the mimetype of the content added and remove it directly.

Comment: correct - regarding UI-based changes: perhaps, you'll also have to change filter config of Alfresco.DNDUpload (for HTML5 drag & drop upload: http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-head/symbols/Alfresco.DNDUpload.html)
I'd generally recommend to do both: add UI config & policy

Comment: You're right, the flash-upload.js was just an example, he probably needs to apply his new filter to all the client-side javascript libraries: flash-upload.js, html-upload,js, file-upload.js and dnd-upload.js

Comment: I tried in adding filters in file-upload.js and html-upload.js. In file-upload.js, I added filter in section "defaultShowConfig:
      {
         siteId: null, ....,
         filter: [".exe"],...,
         username: null
      }"

But this didn't do any change.

Comment: Hi Aneesh, maybe you can add your js file in jsfiddle/dropbox/my.alfresco so I can see what you're doing

Comment: Please have a look in to https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/adding-filters-mimetypes-10032013-0455 . This is the only change I made in the file-upload.js.

Comment: Hi Aneesh, you need to make the change to all the files I've mentions above. If you've got Flash it will probably use the flash uploader. And second if you add the image file, in the filter it means it will ONLY let you select image files. So at first start with {description: description, extensions: "*.jpg"} to test if you can only upload a jpg file

Answer (score 3):

I had to struggle with the same problem and finally I found this [Alfresco: Mime Type Blocker](https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-mimetype-blocker) kindly "offered" by Angel Borroy.

> Alfresco handles every file format, in fact there is no limitation out
>   of the box in order to restrict allowed MIME types. Executables,
>   databases and any other potentially harmful content can be stored
>   inside.
>
> This addon provides an Alfresco extension to define a mime type black
>   list at alfresco-global.properties and one aspect Mime Type
>   Restrictable to define which folders shall apply this restriction.

Basically you define the blacklist of mime type to be blocked setting properly a variable in the `alfresco-global.properties` file:

> ```
> ## Samples
> ## STARTS WITH video = video*
> ##   ENDS WITH xml   = *xml 
> ##    CONTAINS pdf   = *pdf*
> ##    EXACTLY ONE    = application/octet-stream
> ## MANY (use pipes)  = application/octet-stream|application/zip|video*
> mimetypes.restricted.expression=video*
> ```

Then

> by using default Alfresco Share folder action Manage Aspects, Mime
>   Type Restrictable aspect can be applied to desired folders.

so you can decide to which folder apply this rule.

**EDIT 2016-05-27**

I also found and alternative to this method, which is based on rules usage:

First of all create a simple javascript webscript, say `block-document.js` that throws an exception :

```
function main()
{
    var name = document.name;
    var siteName = document.siteShortName;
    var parent = document.parent;
    throw "Unsupported file format";
}
main();
```

then upload it using Alfresco Share into the `Repository>Data Dictionary>Scripts` folder.

[image: script upload]

In order to set a rule on a folder (and also, if needed, on subfolders as well) select the desired folder and on the **Folder Actions** menu select **Manage Rules**

[image: Share folder's Folder Action menu]

After that create a rule that fires the previous script when a new document with a certain mime type (or more than one mime type) is added to the folder

[image: Rule definition]

The advantage of this solution, compared to the previous one is that this rule can be applied also to subfolders simply checking the checkbox option, whereas the aspect must be applied to each single folder.

The user while uploading the document immediately gets warned that the file has not been added to the repository, no matter which uploading strategy he's using.